# enable offline capabilities ionic 3 firestore

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, offline

Could you please some one help me to enable my ionic 3 app to be as offline first. I am creating single code for web , android,ios and windows phone. I need to enable the offline capabilities. Google document says to use the bellow code.

But I am not sure where to add the bellow code, I used environment.ts file for configuration and inside the constructor of app.component.ts file , I included the bellow code.

```
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence().then(function() {
  // Initialize Cloud Firestore through firebase
  var db = firebase.firestore();
  }).catch(function(err) {
  if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
      // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
      // in one tab at a a time.
      // ...
  } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
      // The current browser does not support all of the
      // features required to enable persistence
      // ...
  }
```

});

My first doubt is , Where should i paste this code, Do I need to add more code to enable offline persistence or is this enough?

Second one is, do I need to follow different approach for different platform, like for android, need to follow the android tutorial in firestore documentation and for web different. Or enabling web will be automatically work for other platforms like ios,android and web?

Also , I am getting the bellow error while i used the above code in the constructor of app.component.ts

```
WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_firebase___default.a.firestore is not a function
```

Stack is :

TypeError    : __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_firebase___default.a.firestore is not a function
       at new MyApp (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:8712:58)
    `enter code here`at createClass (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12859:20)
    at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12700:37)
    at createViewNodes (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14158:53)
    at createRootView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14047:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15472:42)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView]

Thanks

Comment: Did you found a solution?